# func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) nearly matches optional requirement

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UIViewController` like this:

```
class ViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
     // datasource methods...
}       

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    }
}
```

But I get this warning:

> Instance method 'tableView(*:canEditRowAt:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'tableView(*:canFocusRowAt:)' of protocol 'UITableViewDelegate'

And I can't remove that warning.

How can I remove that warning?

I have to commit the Xcode project for the company I work without any warnings and I can't find how to suppress the warning.

Comment: It works fine for me. Try cutting removing the function and typing it again, using auto-complete.

Comment: Are you using Swift 2 or 3?

Comment: @penatheboss I have edited the question added the way I implement the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource

Comment: @rmaddy I'm using Swift 3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the `tableView(_:canEditRowAt:)` method is from the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, not the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol. Move it to the other extension.